# SlickGrid find the height

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I need help  I use SlickGrid for the my  table. After each row should display div with the buttons. I need to somehow calculate the height of the row to locate the button. My code `

```
grid.onMouseEnter.subscribe(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    var cell = grid.getCellFromEvent(e);
    $("#contextMenu")
        .data("row", cell.row)
        .css("top", "???")
        .css("left", "100px")
        .show();
});
```

`
How do I calculate the top ?

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
$(cell.row).height();
```

or you can also check `slick.core.js` and `slick.grid.js` what is the default row-height given(you can also configure that)